# Refactor to reduce duplication across several event listeners

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which repeats some patterns

```
  document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    myFn.eventActionTrigger();
    myFn.spinner("on");
  });
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    myFn.eventActionTrigger();
    myFn.spinner("on");
  });
  document.querySelector(".seeMore").addEventListener("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    myFn.eventActionTrigger("seeMore");
    myFn.spinner("on");
  });
```

How could i refactor the listening Event functions to have a generic function which takes arguments and depending on that, listen the rights event and trigger the inner functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create function that takes selector, event, and callback function.

```js
function action1() {alert('Form submited')}
function action2() {alert('Button clicked')}

function eventFunc(selector, event, callback) {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    callback()
  })
}

eventFunc('form', 'submit', action1)
eventFunc('button', 'click', action2)
```

```html
<form action=""><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
<button>click</button>
```

If you want to pass multiple callback functions you can use rest parameter on callback and run each one using `forEach` loop

```js
function action1() {alert('Form')}
function another() {alert('Another function')}
function action2() {alert('Button')}

function eventFunc(selector, event, ...callback) {
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    callback.forEach(c => c())
  })
}

eventFunc('form', 'submit', action1, another)
eventFunc('button', 'click', action2)
```

```html
<form action=""><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
<button>click</button>
```

Comment: So by using multiple callbacks, `myFn.eventActionTrigger` could be refactored to only contain generic code while the `"seeMore"` part could be turned into another callback? That could work, depending on what's in the function. Can't upvote nor downvote until OP shows that function.

Comment: @Terminus In that case he could do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1799/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a higher-order function `makeListener` that captures arguments (like that passed to the `myFn.eventActionTrigger` method) using closure and returns a customized event listener:

```js
function makeListener(arg) {
  return function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    myFn.eventActionTrigger(arg)
    myFn.spinner('on')
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', makeListener())
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', makeListener())
document.querySelector('.seeMore').addEventListener('click', makeListener('seeMore'))


// Boilerplate:
var myFn = {
  eventActionTrigger: console.log.bind(console, 'eventActionTrigger:'),
  spinner: console.log.bind(console, 'spinner:')
}
```

```html
<form>Form
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<button>Button</button>
<div class="seeMore">See More</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
function addEventListener(selector, listenerType) {

  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener(listenerType, function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if (selector.charAt(0) === '.')
       myFn.eventActionTrigger(selector);
    else
       myFn.eventActionTrigger();

    myFn.spinner("on");
  });
}
```

you would then update your code to this:

```
addEventListener("form", "submit");
addEventListener("button", "click");
addEventListener(".seeMore", "click");
```